# Strange files : *.dll.a * .la What are they? ( VLC windows build ) How to use them on Windows if possible?

Tags: linux, cygwin, mingw, vlc, libvlc

I wanted to write small streaming software using VLC compoents on windows. So i look for : lib and headers file for VLC on windows. Instead of compiling it , to make it faster i looked for ready builds for windows. And i found on:  http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win32/last/

I download it (debug) : Find include file directory and lib. But lib directory contains  trange (at least for me) file extensions such as `libvlc.la` and `libvlc.dll.a`

What are they? Can i use them in Visual C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.la` files are libtool convenience libraries, they're useless and only cause trouble (in this case).

The `.a` files are (import) libraries for GCC/MinGW, just like `.lib` for MSVC.

VLC can only be built with GCC, because MSVC lacks the proper C99 support. So all debug info will be generated by and for a GNU toolchain (GCC/Binutils/GDB). If you want to use the proper DLL in Visual Studio, you should be able to create an import library from the included `.def` file and the dll.

Comment: So is it possible to compile VLC on windows so that i can easily get static lib (which Visual C++ CAN undestand) files? (with gcc)

Comment: No, I know of no way to get a MSVC `.lib` file out of a GNU toolchain. On the other hand, you could try [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) which should be able to compile VLC, and can be built to use Visual Studio headers, but I don't know how far they have gotten with parsing MSVC headers. C++ is still off-limits, but haven't checked on C. You'll have to build Clang yourself (which isn't hard, just read the [get started](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) page). You should get some help from the Clang mailing list (or perhaps here, if you have a specific question).

Comment: One thing: the VLC GUI is C++ (Qt actually) so you can't use Clang to get that bit, you'll have to try and build only the VLC library). You'll of course have to build all prerequisites in the same fashion, as they are only provided for GCC...